# Hide XML data in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am creating an app in WPF. I need to store the data related to user. I had figured how to create a folder in documents and stored the data in a XML file.

But my problem is `it is easily editable by any persons and change the value in the XML file`.

Is there any way to hide those information? OR do i need to make another choice for storing the data?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use compression together with password protection to save the data in a .zip file. Your application then can easily decompress the zipped file into its XML original and read the settings there. You can use SharpZipLib from NuGet to achieve this.

Comment: When decompressing is the file stored anywhere?

Comment: The original XML file is not stored anywhere. The compressed and encrypted file is stored wherever you as the developer would choose. However, since the zip file is password protected, people would not be able to open it and edit the XML.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. No, you use a stream to decompress the file, you do not need to "save a temporary file" to access it.